# JDIALOG not Seeing Other Classes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, crud, jdialog

I'm currently trying to write a simple CRUD using Java. I've made a separate class to Connect to mySQL Database. I then created a `JFrame` and I used the extends to bind that class to my `JFrame`. I also created a `JDialog` called "FormCadastro", that opens when the user choose some function in a `JMenu`, at this point everything is working fine, the `JDialog` appears from `JFrame` but the problem is that the `JDialog` class is not seeing my "ConnectDataBase" class, and I need to access it when the user clicks "Register" to send data from `JDialog TextFields` to my database.

JDialog Class

```
JButton OkBtn = new JButton("Cadastrar");

OkBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String query = "INSERT INTO dados_pessoais(Codigo, Nome, SobreNome, Endereco, Numero, Bairro, Cidade, UF, Email, Celular, Telefone) VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        //JDialog does not see "con" variable and PreparedStatement class even if i import it using import Classes.ConnectDataBase,
    }
}
```

If I use `extends ConnectDataBase` in the place of `JDialog` at

```
public class FormCadastro extends JDialog
```

I get a lot of errors, so I don't know what to do to access that DataBase 
class in my JDialog.

ConnectDataBase Class

```
public class ConnectDataBase 
{
    private Connection con = null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;

    public void ConnectDataBase() throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            this.con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usuarios", "root", "admin");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexão com o Banco de Dados bem sucedida");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao tentar conectar ao Banco de Dados", "Erro de Conexão", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your JDialog-extending class to use the functionality of the ConnectDataBase, then you have to pass a viable ConnectDataBase into the JDialog class, perhaps in its constructor or via a setter method. Using imports does not magically confer ability. You need to use *composition*.

e.g.,

```
public class FormCadastro extends JDialog {
    private ConnectDataBase connectDataBase;

    public FormCadastro(ConnectDataBase connectDataBase) {
        this.connectDataBase = connectDataBase;

        JButton OkBtn = new JButton("Cadastrar");
        OkBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String query = "INSERT INTO dados_pessoais (Codigo,Nome,SobreNome,Endereco,Numero,Bairro,Cidade,UF,Email,Celular,Telefone) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                // use public methods of your connectDataBase object here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but im yet stuck in this ;/